# Jboss AMQ: Send persistent message from hawtio

Tags: java, jboss, redhat, jboss-amq

We are developing an application that uses redhat jboss AMQ. We are migrating from version 6.0 to 6.1 where we have the new webconsole `hawtio`. In order to test feature of our app I need to send `PERSISTENT` message to queue. In version 6.0 if I wanted to send persistent message I just needed to check checkbox, but in hawtio I see no such option. I believe I need to add additional header, but I don't know exactly which one, or is there another option to achieve what I want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add the JMS header "JMSDeliveryMode" as 2. As per the jms-1.1.jar

```
package javax.jms;
public interface DeliveryMode {
    int NON_PERSISTENT = 1;
    int PERSISTENT = 2;
}
```